# How can I save a User's uploaded image to a temp file that I can access later, but gets deleted after that

Tags: c#, asp.net

I've created an image uploader for users to upload/crop their profile pics. When a user uploads a file, it gets saved to a file that gets accessed immediately after for them to crop it.

I've tried using Path.GetTempPath() as well as Path.GetTempFileName(), but my cropper was unable to locate the file locations for some reason. 
Any suggestions are greatly appreciated.

UPDATE: So I added File.Delete(filePath) to the end of btnCropClick, but I get an error saying The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. How can I "release" that file to be deleted instantly ?

Below is the code for where a user uploads their orignal image of choice

```
protected void btnUploadClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Upload Original Image Here
        String UploadFileName = "";
        String UploadFilePath = "";

        if (fileUploader.HasFile)
        {
            String ext = Path.GetExtension(fileUploader.FileName).ToLower();
            if (ext == ".jpg" || ext == ".jpeg" || ext == ".png")
            {
                UploadFileName = "orig_" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ext;
                UploadFilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("images/OriginalImages"), UploadFileName);
                try
                {
                    fileUploader.SaveAs(UploadFilePath); //TODO: Need to make this a temp file that gets "destroyed" later

                    imgUpload.ImageUrl = "images/OriginalImages/" + UploadFileName;
                    panCrop.Visible = true;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    lblMsg.Text = "Error! Please Try Again. ";
                }
            }
            else
            {
                lblMsg.Text = "Invalid File Type Selected. | Please Choose .jpg, .jpeg, or .png file only.";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            lblMsg.Text = "Please Click 'Choose File' & Select An Image To Upload";
        }
    }
```

And here is the code for the cropper (Not sure anything in here needs to be changed, but I'll include it anyway for context & relevancy

```
    protected void btnCropClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Crop Image Here & Save
        String fileName = Path.GetFileName(imgUpload.ImageUrl);
        String filePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("images/OriginalImages"), fileName);
        String cropFileName = "";
        String cropFilePath = "";

        if (File.Exists(filePath))
        {
            System.Drawing.Image orgImg = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filePath);

            Rectangle CropArea = new Rectangle(
                Convert.ToInt32(X.Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(Y.Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(W.Value),
                Convert.ToInt32(H.Value)
                );

            try
            {
                Bitmap bitMap = new Bitmap(CropArea.Width, CropArea.Height);
                using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bitMap))
                {
                    g.DrawImage(orgImg, new Rectangle(0, 0, bitMap.Width, bitMap.Height), CropArea, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);

                    Bitmap resized = new Bitmap(bitMap, new Size(200, 200)); //Resize image to save as 200x200

                    cropFileName = "crop_" + fileName; //+UserID so each fileName is unique
                    cropFilePath = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("images/CroppedImages"), cropFileName);
                    resized.Save(cropFilePath); //Where final, cropped image is saved
                    imgHeadshot.ImageUrl = "images/CroppedImages/" + cropFileName;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }

            panCrop.Visible = false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Depending on your hosting environment, you may not have access to the standard temp folder.  Just create a temp subfolder in your app folder and use that instead.

Comment: if you move the file to a folder outside temp, you will have control as to when it is deleted

Comment: My server environment is Windows/IIS.
Hmm, are you suggesting to just create my own folder (named "temp" or whatever) & then just manually (or with a script, code, or whatever) delete the file?

Comment: UPDATE: So I added File.Delete(filePath) to the end of btnCropClick, but I get an error saying The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process. How can I "release" that file to be deleted instantly ?

Comment: @Justin, - Path.GetTempPath() applies to windows environment, and, sounds like you're developing asp.net webforms, where your image files are stored in <website virtual dir>/images/OriginalImages and <website virtual directory>/mages/CroppedImages. Can you verify that files are indeed there? File.Delete() is looking for an actual physical path, not  <website virtual directory>/mages/..../ .

Comment: Nope. Not using a virtual directory surprisingly (ISS > 'View Virtual Directories' is empty). Files are in actual physical paths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was able to dispose of the original file by adding:

```
orgImg.Dispose();
bitMap.Dispose();
File.Delete(filePath);
```

to the end of btnCropClick method.